# Why is this a quotient map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology

Is there a direct way to see that $p \times id : [0,1]^2 \rightarrow S^1 \times [0,1]$ is a quotient map with $(p \times id)(x,y) = (e^{ix},y)$? By direct way, I mean is there an obvious argument why this has to be a quotient map? I somehow feel that there is an obvious reason why this has to be one, but I don't see it.

Comment: What do you know about continuous maps and compact sets?

Comment: continuous maps map compact sets to compact sets. do you mean this?

Comment: And what do you know about compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: they are closed in the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed an obvious reason:

Continuous maps from quasicompact spaces to Hausdorff spaces are closed.

And continuous and closed surjective maps are quotient maps.

Comment: ah, so a continuous map $f:X \rightarrow Y$, where $Y$ is Hausdorff and $X$ is compact is always closed. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One can use either of the following three facts to show that $q\times 1_Y$ is closed.

> **Fact 1:** If $q:X\to Z$ is a quotient map, and $Y$ is locally compact, then $q×1_Y:X×Y\to Z×Y$ is a quotient map.

In your case, $Y=[0,1]$ which is locally compact.

A map is called *perfect* if it's closed and all fibers are compact.

> **Fact 2:** If $q:X\to Z$ is a surjective perfect map, then $q×1_Y$ is a closed surjection for any space $Y$, so it is a quotient map.

Note that a map from a compact to a Hausdorff space is always perfect. This also implies

> **Fact 3:** If $q:X\to Z$ is any surjective map, $X$ is compact, $Z$ is Hausdorff, and $Y$ is compact Hausdorff, then $q×1_Y$ is a closed surjection, as $X\times Y$ is compact and $Z\times Y$ is Hausdorff.

This is of course the statement that you would most likely use in your situation, since all your spaces are compact Hausdorff. The other facts can be applied if some of your spaces are not.